# Problem with HTML input in Asp.net Content page,

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

```
 <input type="text" id="txt_Respondby"  />
```

I am using JQuery UI DateTimePicker in the input above. it works well.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#txt_Respondby').datetimepicker();
        });
  </script>
```

I have included the required JS  and there is no problem with the calender

Since I want to get the value selected from the calender in server side. I changed the input to `runat="server"` When I tried to run it the calender wasn't popping out. How can I access in server side the value selected in the calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('input[id$=txt_Respondby]').datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Is your page using a Master Page?  If so, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" will be appended to your ID's where the control has runat="server".  Therefore if you look for id txt_RespondBy it won't find it because the Id is now ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_RespondBy.

Comment: No The calender is in a content page

Comment: @Mano, Edit: Yeah I mean't uses a Master Page, not in the Master Page itself.  That means it'll generate the ID's with the ctl00_ prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
$("#<%=txt_Respondby.ClientID%>").datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed it to a server control. The rendered page changed the name to something like content...txt_RespondBy... In order to fix the problem you either need to use a wildcard in your JQuery or if you are using ASP.Net 4.0 set the ClientID property to Static.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Request["name_of_your_field"]
```

or in you js

```
  $(function () {
        $('#<%= txt_SendAt.ClientID  %>').datetimepicker();
    });
```

this way you get the text box id on the javascript(when you add runat="server" the final id is not the one in your aspx file (an other fun stuff about webforms)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to put runat="server" to access data from text box

you can do it like this

```
Request.Form["txt_SendAt"].ToString();
```

Comment: i am not using a form, I am using master page and content page.

Comment: If you're using ASP.Net, then you are using a form.

Comment: @Mano: When using master pages, the form is in the master page.